# C++ InorderSuccessor() Returns NULL

Tags: c++

**Problem::: The inorderSuccessor  returns null.**

```
// this method will test getMin_Node() and inorderSuccessor() by printing.
        void inorder_min_test(String * str){
            String *min = getMin_Node(str);

            while(min != nullptr){
                cout << "NEXT IS ===> " << min->getStr() << endl;
                cout << "before inorder" << str << ", " << min << endl;
                min = inorderSuccessor(str, min);
                if(min == nullptr) {
                    cout << "MINIMUM NODE IS NULL " << endl;
                }
            }
        }
```

**// Getting Smallest Node**

```
 // returns Minimum Node
        String* getMin_Node(String* node) {
            if(node->left != nullptr){
                node = getMin_Node(node->left);
            }
            return node;
        }
```

**// Returns In-order Successor**

```
 // returns successor.
        String* inorderSuccessor(String* root, String* p) {
            String* temp = NULL;

            while (root != NULL){
                if(p < root){  **// <-- I wrote operator < ()**
                    temp = root;
                    root = root->left;
                }
                else{
                    root = root->right;
                }
            }

            cout << temp << endl;
            return temp;
        }
```

**// It OUTPUTS: **

```
NEXT IS ===> MAN
before inorder 0x13c704080, 0x13c704080
0x0
MINIMUM NODE IS NULL
```

--- Thank you. ---

String is a node with c type string. I wrote operator <() to compare the String nodes.

Comment: In C++ you should be using `nullptr` consistently instead of C's typeless `NULL`. Also are you sure your comparator works on `String*` and not just `String&`?

Comment: It's not clear how that tree is populated, as there may be a problem with assembling it vs. navigating.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review our page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and post the simplest code example that we can run and test. The bug may be in the code you haven't posted, and in the process of preparing the example you are likely to discover the bug yourself.